# React-query onError not executing on thrown Error

Tags: reactjs, react-query

**Query**:

```
const { data: post, isError, error } = useQuery<PostResponseDto>(
  ['fetch-post', params],
  () => fetchPost(params!.postId),
  {
    refetchOnMount: true,
    onError: (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    },
  },
);
```

**Fetch function**:

```
export const fetchPost = async (webId: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get(`${API_URL}/post/${webId}`);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

**Axios response interceptor**:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response: AxiosResponse) => {
    const accessToken = response.headers[ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER];
    const refreshToken = response.headers[REFRESH_TOKEN_HEADER];

    if (accessToken && refreshToken) {
      localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER, accessToken);
      localStorage.setItem(REFRESH_TOKEN_HEADER, refreshToken);
    }

    return response;
  },
  async (error: AxiosError) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    const errorHeader = error.response?.headers.error;

    if (
      errorHeader &&
      errorHeader === EXPIRED_ACCESS_TOKEN_ERROR &&
      // @ts-ignore
      !originalRequest._retry
    ) {
      // @ts-ignore
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      await refreshAccessToken();
      return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
    } else if (errorHeader && errorHeader === EXPIRED_REFRESH_TOKEN_ERROR) {
      // do nothing for now
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
```

All I'm getting in the console is this (which is as it should be as I'm throwing an `Error`):
[image]

As you can see in case of a failed Promise I am throwing `new Error(error)`.
`console.log(err)` in `onError` callback is not printing anything. On top of that, variable `isError` is always false and `error` is always null. I can surely say it is not triggering because even I print some string, there is nothing in the console.

**Why is thrown `Error` not propagating and onError callback not trigering?**

Comment: i don't see anything immediately wrong with the code, though it is interesting that you would catch an error just to throw it again? `error` is of type Error, so `new Error(error)` might put an error into an error. Do you have any axios interceptors setup? Otherwise, a codesandbox reproduction would help

Comment: Yeah, it is maybe unnecessary to catch and then throw an Error, but even if I remove try-catch block, the problem remains. Yes, I have axios interceptors (edited the post), but removing it does nothing. If I log the error in the catch block, I get the actual AxiosError, so the interceptor shouldn't be making problems here.

Comment: please try implementing `fetchPost` as just: `throw new Error("error")`. You should see it working. Then, try it with axios or fetch without any interceptors. This approach narrows it down.